# Chronological List of Events

Tags: civievent, dates

Please can we have our list of events in chronological order, currently they are in reverse chronological order.  I have tried clicking the Start Date but it only turn that page of events up the other way all subsequent pages remain the same

Comment: On which screen are you looking for?

Comment: Welcome - you will find that the more information in your Question the better the quality of Answers eg, as above, provide a url (without your domain), and mention the version of civicrm.

Comment: Also if you have a support partner who has helped you configure and implement civicrm it may be worth asking them as it may not be clear if there is some customisation. Another way to help others help you is to see if you can see the same issue on one of the public demo sites eg https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/

Comment: The other possibility is that you have your Events displayed via the CMS (Drupal or WP) and it may therefore not be a CiviCRM solution that you need.